# Is it possible to merge two reducers into one?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I would like to merge two reducers, the first being created as a generic one and the second one would be more specific to it's own state. Both these reducers would not handle the same cases. Merging these would only result in default case being duplicated, the default case always returning the default state anyways. This would help as I would only test the generic one once.

In case you were thinking about `reduceReducers` or `combineReducers`, that would not work since I have many "special" reducers with every one of them having the same action type to handle and all of those reducers have a different part of the state to modify.

```js
const initialState = {
  byId : {},
  ids: []
}

const dogsReducer = ({ dogs: state = initialState, ...restOfState }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INITIALIZE:
      return {
        byId : _.keyBy(state.dogs, 'id'),
        ids: state.map(({id}) => id)
      }
    case RESET:
      return initialState
    case SPECIFIC_DOG_ACTION:
      ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const catsReducer = ({ cats: state = initialState, ...restOfState}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INITIALIZE:
      return {
        byId : _.keyBy(state, 'id'),
        ids: state.map(({id}) => id)
      }
    case RESET:
      return initialState
    case SPECIFIC_CAT_ACTION:
      ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I want to isolate the following cases : `INITIALIZE` and `RESET` in a generic switch/case function or a generic reducer, so I would only have to test those cases once and not in every reducer. There would be more generic cases in the future, that's why I want to avoid repetition.

This is the expected result :

```js
const genericReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INITIALIZE:
      return {
        byId : _.keyBy(state.dogs, 'id'),
        ids: state.map(({id}) => id)
      }
    case RESET:
      return initialState
    default:
      return state
   }
}

const dogsReducer = ({ dogs: state = initialState, ...restOfState }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SPECIFIC_DOG_ACTION:
      ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const catsReducer = ({ cats: state = initialState, ...restOfState}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SPECIFIC_CAT_ACTION:
      ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const finalCatsReducer = mergeReducers(catsReducer, genericReducer)
const finalDogsReducer = mergeReducers(dogsReducer, genericReducer)
```

Comment: _"How that would be done in plain javascript ?"_ - Like you just did ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzjrvhy8/)). So what's the actual problem/error?

Comment: what does not work with the result?

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to be asking about. You might consider describing what problem this is supposed to solve, because there's likely a better way to solve it than writing a function that generically combines switch statements. See [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If they have different cases and default is the same what was wrong with the commented single function approach?

Comment: Fine but you have oversimplified the whole concept and not provided a practical use case enough for a productive answer. Note the question above about *"what problem are you trying to solve"*

Comment: @obscure18 for some reason this was put on hold, but check this: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/oKaWRm?editors=0011

It contains several concepts. But the most important one is that values are returned in array since you can have overlapping switches and you need to know all values returned.

Comment: @zvona Thank you very much ! I think your answer will truly help me.

Comment: @ggorlen I have edited this so it can be reopened.

Comment: @charlietfl I have applied your comments.

Comment: @Andreas I think you misunderstood the question. I added a lot of details.

Comment: After your nth edit changing the question completely my comment might not be relevant anymore but I can live with that...

Comment: I voted to reopen. The question still has room for improvement, but asking about X instead of Y makes it a lot more concrete and answerable. Further suggestions are to improve the title to ask specifically about merging reducers and clean up the numerous edits to create a succinct, clear exposition of the problem and your question X. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @ggorlen still learning here, I have fixed the question, hoping to get some more useful answers from fellows devs here :)

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine using the following however I want to say that would have a similar effect to just putting them all flat. The only added benefit I can see is that the specific switch cases won't be verified unless the general cases fail.

```
const genericSwitch = type => {
  switch (type) {
    case 1:
      do something x

    default: //specificSwitch
      switch (type) {
        case 2:
          do something y
      default:
          return z
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was about merge not about joining. Isn't it?

Comment: @Jackkobec it is, but it outputs exactly the same result as required.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to wrap into the upper method:

```
const combinedSwitch = type => {
  const result = genericSwitch(type);
  return result === z ? specificSwitch(type) : result;
}

const genericSwitch = type => {
  switch (type) {
    case 1:
      do something x
    default:
      return z
  }
}

const specificSwitch = type => {
  switch (type) {
    case 2:
      do something y
    default:
      return z
  }
}
```

Comment: I would start with the specific one rather than the generic one. Thank you very much, it is a simple and easy to understand alternative.